# Добавления класса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет помогите. У меня есть несколько тегов strong и у них нету классов. Как можно добавить классы не заходя в html.

Comment: Вот тебе статья уважаемый: https://ruseller.com/jquery?id=19

Comment: спасибо, никогда с jquery не работал

Comment: Только одного меня раздражает вопрос...))))???  ` Как можно добавить классы не заходя в html.`  Что значит `не заходя в html`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1: добавим всем найденным тегам strong на странице класс new_class, при этом, их старые классы останутся без изменения:
`$('strong').addClass('new_class');`

Вариант 2: найти все strong на странице и изменить им класс на new_class, удалив у них имеющиеся:
`$('strong').attr('class', 'new_class');`

И всё это работает лишь подключив библиотеку [jQuery](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery):
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Допустим у меня 2 тега без классов и мне нужно присвоить первому какой та класс а второму не обязательно, как мне лучше всего сделать или вообще это возможно?

Comment: @Алеша очень советую, сейчас с чистым JS работать сложней, если тебе нужно выполнять простые вещи типа этих, изучи jQuery к примеру [здесь](http://www.wisdomweb.ru/JQ/jquery-first.php), у него также много полезных [плагинов](http://plugins.jquery.com/tag/jquery/), которые тебе явно приглянуться

Comment: @Алеша из всех dom элементов, первый ты можешь найти так: `$('strong:first-child').attr('class', 'new_class');` последний так: `$('strong:last-child').attr('class', 'new_class');` если нужно совершить действия с элементами скажем 2,3,5 (между), тогда нужно в функции перебирать элементы, здесь тебе поможет `.each`

Answer (score 3):

```
$('strong').addClass('class');
```